# $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] not giving the right ip address

Tags: php, ip, localhost

I'm making a form with PHP and I want to keep record of the User's IP Addresses. This is the snip-it of code I used:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ip" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>" />
```

When I open the code up in XAMPP and read the source, the value had an IP address different than what was mine:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ip" value="::1" />
```

Does this IP address normally happen when I use it in a localhost (XAMPP)?
If not, are there any alternatives into grabbing the user's IP address?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> `<input type="hidden" name="ip" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>" />`

Don't do that. Get the request from `$_SERVER` when the form is submitted. Getting it when the form is generated and storing it in the form just gives people the opportunity to change it.

> `Does this IP address normally happen when I use it in a localhost (XAMPP)?`

Yes. Getting the local IP (IPv6) address is normal when you request a page from localhost.

Comment: Thx for the tip on changing it when submitted ;)

Comment: What if someone changes his ip address somehow (like using VPN or anything)? Then I will not get the correct ip of that PC. is it?

Answer (score 28):

IP `::1` is "localhost" in IPv6 version.  Your machine is configured with IPv6 - and hence you're getting this IP address.  Probably, when you deploy your application on the live server, IPv6 will not be configured on the server and your app will get a more familiar IPv4 address (e.g. aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd).

On another note, `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` may not always contain the right address.  It's better to use:

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
    $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```

Comment: Belated, but also keep in mind if you use HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR, you cannot trust this to only allow access to local IPs for secure admin pages, because that head can be spoofed very easily. In fact, StackOverflow once fell victim to this very thing and fortunately a friendly user reported it to them.

Comment: @smdrager : so what's the secure way to get user machine's IP address ? I need to allow my page to open for only a single IP.

Comment: @sqlchild If you need it to work for any IP, then why do you even care about the IP addresses?  There's no foolproof way to get the IP address. The code I showed is what I've used - and it covers all but few exceptions.

Comment: @AleksG : I need a page on my website to open for only a given allowed IP and not for any other. Then how to do it ?

Comment: @sqlchild Then check for customer's IP and compare with the required one.  The other alternative is to edit your .htaccess or the server config to only allow access to the page from specific IP's.  However in either case, keep in mind that IP can be spoofed easily - and there's absolutely nothing you can do about it.  Protecting by IP isn't very safe in general.

Comment: @AleksG : fine, so is there any alternative for this instead of using IP blocking?

Comment: @sqlchild take your pick: username/password, user certificates, tunnelling.

Comment: @AleksG : Could you please provide some articles, help urls regarding using user certificates and tunnelling as an alternative to IP blocking.

Comment: It's been a few days, but... we use both IP address and a a special query string value (kind of a password). Obviously this is not foolproof, but acts as a sort of 2-factor authentication. Needing both is not an easily guessable combination.

Answer (score 4):

'::1' is the IPV6 version of localhost (or 127.0.0.1).

Open port 80 and visit the page from your IP Address. Should work fine then :).

Answer (score 4):

1). You don't need to add `<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>` to form. In this case it's easy to forge it (actually it's easy any case). Better add IP to data on server side.

2) You can look also to `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']`.
If user have a proxy, some of them (transparent proxies) place real user's IP there.

3) Just note: Data about IP's isn't trustworthy at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually your IP. Albeit your IPv6 IP and not IPv4.

In IPv6, ::1 stands for localhost / 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARTDED_FOR'] != '') {
                $ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
            } else {
                $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            }
```

This code returns ip of the client. If you think this is the server IP, you are probably right because your server is (presumably) hosted on your pc.
Since your client (the pc) and the server run on the same pc, they both have the same ip.
If you don't understand this, you should really do some research into ips, local ips and all that stuff.