# php - Local vs Remote Settings

Tags: php

How would I go about doing something like:

```
if ( localhost )
{
   //use these settings
} else if ( remote )
{
   // use these settings
}
```

I tried using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] but according to this page: [$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] not giving the right ip address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982277/serverremote-addr-not-giving-the-right-ip-address), IPv6 won't always be set on remote.

Comment: There will **always** be a remote address, regardless of protocol.

Comment: "IPv6 won't always be set on remote" => What is that supposed to mean? IPv6 is not something that is set or not set, it's a protocol. If you are using it, then the IP will be in v6 format; if not, in v4.

Comment: Yes, but the page I linked seems to indicate that you can't be sure whether it is IPv6 or IPv4. So what is a way to always get the correct ip?

Comment: @ Jon, I don't know. See link, some guy said " Probably, when you deploy your application on the live server, IPv6 will not be configured on the server and your app will get a more familiar IPv4 address (e.g. aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd)."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if you are on one of the local addresses (IPv4 or IPv6):

```
$locals = array('127.0.0.1','::1');

if(in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $locals)){
    // local
} else {
    // remote
}
```