# How should I call this function? PHP

Tags: php, function, ip, port, listen

How should I call this function? I'm new to PHP. Here's my code... but I have an error

> Notice: Undefined variable: ip in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPTest\ip.php on line 19

```
    <?php
    function getRealIpAddr(){
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
        {
          $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        }
        elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
        {
          $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        }
        else
        {
          $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }
        return $ip;
    }
    call_user_func('getRealIpAddr', '$ip');
    echo $ip;
    ?>
```

**UPDATE**

> Strange reason, I'm using Windows 10, localhost, xampp and google Chrome this script doesn't provide me an ip address! That's why a corrected code was empty... Thought it was some kind of errors or something

**Second UPDATE**

> If you're getting no ip like me, you may try this solution [on httpd.conf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699454/should-a-mamp-return-1-as-ip-on-localhost)

Comment: for update: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699454/should-a-mamp-return-1-as-ip-on-localhost

Comment: are u getting this: ::1 ??? and want to get this 127.0.0.1 ?? for UPDATE

Comment: @devpro empty and just updated my httpd.conf to `Listen 127.0.0.1:80`, restarted still didn't work :o

Comment: this question will help u: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982277/serverremote-addr-not-giving-the-right-ip-address

Comment: More likely the issue is `call_user_func('getRealIpAddr', '$ip');` remove the single quotes around `'$ip'` Plus there is no parameter defined on that function to receive `$ip` anyway and it would need to be passed by reference the way you are doing it!

Comment: It's working now, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is very clear `$ip` is not defined:

**Modified Code:**

```
<?
function getRealIpAddr(){
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
        $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
        $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
        $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}

$ip = getRealIpAddr(); // your function
echo $ip;
?>
```

If you want to use `$ip` variable that you defined inside the function than note that scope of the `$ip` is limited into the function.

You can not call this variable outside the function. for this you need to store it in a variable as like above mentioned example (`$ip = getRealIpAddr();`).

Answer (score 4):

Your function `return`s the IP address, so assign a variable to the return value of the function, like so:

`$ip = getRealIpAddr();`

Answer (score -1):

You can't access to a variable declared inside a function, but with the return statement you can do :

```
echo getRealIpAddr();
```

Instead of :

```
call_user_func('getRealIpAddr', '$ip');
echo $ip;
```