# When I Request::ip() in Laravel 5.2 why it return ::1

Tags: php, request, ip, laravel-5

I'm try to surf the internet and I found this code but it return ip ::1 (That mean ?) I know that is IPv6 loopback 127.0.0.1 but how to get IPv4 from this code ?

or This is right way to get it ?

**EventServiceProvider.php**

```
...
protected $listen = [
     'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => [
    'App\Listeners\UpdateLastLoginOnLogin@handle',
],
...
```

and this **UpdateLastLoginOnLogin.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Listeners;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Auth;
use Request;


class UpdateLastLoginOnLogin
{
    public function handle($event)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->last_login_ip = Request::ip();
        $user->last_login_at = Carbon::now();
        $user->save();
    }
}
```

when this code has run it will return ::1 in my database

Thank you

Comment: You can check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982277/serverremote-addr-not-giving-the-right-ip-address):

> IP ::1 is "localhost" in IPv6 version. Your machine is configured with IPv6 - and hence you're getting this IP address. Probably, when you deploy your application on the live server, IPv6 will not be configured on the server and your app will get a more familiar IPv4 address (e.g. aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd).

Comment: @OsamaSayed That's mean this code is correct ? and maybe get IPv4 if server has configure in IPv4 right ?

Comment: Oh many Thanks @OsamaSayed I has configure Listen in Apache Server from 80 to 0.0.0.0:80 and BANG!! that's return IPv4.
[https://www.rackaid.com/blog/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-apache-server/]

Comment: Awesome!! You are welcome :)