# $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] not working on live server, please what is the way out(PHP)

Tags: php

I need to get the name of computer or phone device that visited by website. `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` function isn't working on live server, but it's working on localhost. Please put me through.

I used the function on localhost, it worked perfectly, but not working on live server.

```
$computer_name = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

expected result should be for example

```
'Desmond' <br/>

echo $computer_name; //Desmond
```

Comment: What error / content did you get on a live server?

Comment: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` returns an IP

Comment: Can you refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982277/serverremote-addr-not-giving-the-right-ip-address

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to get a hostname from an IP this would be a legit method.

With this method ,

```
$computer_name = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

You're only getting the IP address. To translate it to hostname , you're going to require another function from php `gethostbyaddr`

Your code will look something like this :-

```
<?php
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

echo $hostname;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks to you bro, I just finished trying the code, however, returned the IP not the name of the system.

Comment: Then you should try it with `$_REQUEST` @SammyR

Answer (score -1):

You can use this in live server

```
$computer_name = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
```

Comment: Instead of checking with `array_key_exists`, it's better to check with `empty`, as sometimes those values are present, but are blank.

Comment: Thanks bro, however this returned no response.